# Double header bar on Android DatePicker when fragments are reopened

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment, android-datepicker

I'm running into this weird bug when using the DatePicker Dialog in Android where I get a secondary title bar.  It only happens when I select a date, leave the fragment, then return to it.  I'm doing nothing different when I create a new instance of the fragment, except for checking my state machine for the last selected date (if null I pass in a new `Date()`)

[image]

I'm wondering why this additional bar at the top of the DatePicker shows up, and why it would only show up in a certain scenario.

How to Remove header Title from the `DatePickerDialog` ?

Comment: show us the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `DatePickerDialog`.

use `datePickerDialog.setTitle("");` it will hide the `Title` which you called as `Double header bar`.

Comment: @robotsquidward glad to help you.